# How can I unzip a file which is compressed and encrypted with pkzip?

Tags: encryption, digital-signature, pkzip

How can I unzip a file which is compressed with pkzip file format (pkware)?

Does anyone know about pkware file compression and decryption? I have a file which is zipped with pkware, but I can't open that file, it asks for a digital signature.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to process such files in code and on Windows or Linux, you can use [ZIPBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-zip.php) package of our SecureBlackbox product. ZIPBlackbox supports processing of archives, signed or encrypted using X.509 certificates.

If you meant something else, be more precise with tag selection and formulate the question right.